# RMarkdown image floating

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create an analysis report in Rmarkdown and I am stuck here , below is the example of what I am working on

```
---
output: "pdf_document"
---
```

one small paragraph here

```
![test image](linktoimage)\newline
```

another paragraph below the image

here if i  use `\newline`my image is placed as expected between the paragraphs but the caption is missing else if i remove`\newline` my image is randomly placed at the bottom after rendering the document.

Kindly help me , I tried placing `extra_dependencies: "float"` in the YAML header still the result is same. I am working in emacs editor and am using basic markdown language and not r chunks. Kindly help me what I am missing here to get my images in place with caption and not floating.

Many thanks in advance.

floating and it is all knitted at the end or in random place

Comment: I provided an answer, but if it doesn't work for you I would recommend you to send a link to the image to see if we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found out more about floating images:
Try `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = "!H", out.extra = "")` in your first chunk. `fig.pos` controls floating, and  `!H` stops floating within the document.

I am not sure why your image is being randomly placed. But it could be because of the image size.
But try

```
  ![](linktoimage)
test image
```

to have the caption on the bottom/center of the image.
Or

```
  ![](linktoimage)\newline
test image
```

to have the caption on the bottom left of the image.

Or

```
test image

  ![](linktoimage)\newline
```

To have the caption on the top left of the image

Comment: Thank you for your help, my issue was resolved by placing a tex file in the YAML header which controls the fig positions.

Comment: Great! But you should certainly post your solution as an answer when you get enough reputation (EDIT:which you should have now). [About self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).