# Inserted Photo and/or Kable Table will not stay where it's placed between text in R markdown

Tags: image, format, markdown, inline, kable

I have two things I have been using, neither of which are keeping the image/table exactly where I placed it within the text in R markdown when knitted to a pdf.

`![caption](path)` will place the image where there is space on the page. That is, if the page has space, the image will print between the desired text. However, if the page does not have the space, the text is placed to fill the page and then the image awkwardly inserts itself in the middle of the paragraph on the next page.

I am having a similar problem with my kable tables. I have tried using `latex_options = 'hold_position'`, but this seems to only keep my tables from grouping together.

Is there a way to have my table stay between the text that I want? So if it needs to start a whole new page, to fit it, it can without trying to fill the space with the text below.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = "!H", out.extra = "")` in your first chunk. `fig.pos` controls floating, and  `!H` stops floating within the document.  Good luck!

Comment: My comment above is in my answer answer to the same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133804/rmarkdown-image-floating/65163737#65163737)